# Xamarin UI Test images

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I try to Test an App with Ui Test at Xamarin forms 
My problem is the Upload Images from Ressources ( Android ) 
The normal flow is you take a Picture from device. At UITest you can't Tap on  Android System

On iOS works this code very well

```
    if (action.Equals(PhotoOptionToString(PhotoOption.PHOTOGALLERY)))
                {

      Func<System.IO.Stream> getStreamForExternalStorage = () =>
                    {
                        return System.IO.File.OpenRead("boats.png");

                    };

                    Random randomPic = new Random();
                    string[] Pic = { "boats.png", "holiday.png", "puma.png", "wolf.png", "pizza.png", "railwa.png" };

                    int fIndex = randomPic.Next(0, Pic.Length);

                    var mediafile1 = new MediaFile(Pic[fIndex], () => getStreamForExternalStorage());

                    Console.WriteLine(Pic[fIndex]);

                    await AddReorderImageFromFile(mediafile1);

              }
```

thanks

Comment: hi, did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: Ja, du musst das Bild in ein Byte array laden dann kannst du es hochladen lassen